# error in mysql syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax, foreign-keys

while executing the following query, i get an error that there's an error in the syntax near line 9. since i'm using mysql workbench, i can't really figure out what could be wrong:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proquotes`.`thquotes` (

  `idQuotes` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

  `vAuthorID` VARCHAR(8) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL ,

  `vAuthor` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL ,

  `cQuotes` MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL ,

  `cArabic` MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL ,

  `vReference` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`idQuotes`) ,

  INDEX `vAuthorID` () ,

  CONSTRAINT `vAuthorID`

    FOREIGN KEY ()

    REFERENCES `proquotes`.`author_info` ()

    ON DELETE NO ACTION

    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

table author_info:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proquotes`.`author_info` (  

`vAuthorID` INT NOT NULL ,  `vAuthor` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER 

SET 'utf8' NOT NULL ,  `nQuotes` INT NOT NULL ,  PRIMARY KEY 

(`vAuthorID`) ,  UNIQUE INDEX `vAuthorID_UNIQUE` (`vAuthorID` 

ASC) )DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error appears to be the empty parenthesis at: `INDEX vAuthorID ()`, `FOREIGN KEY ()` and `REFERENCES proquotes.author_info ()`. Those parenthesis should reference one or more table attributes.

For example:

```
INDEX `vAuthorID` (`vAuthorID`) ,
CONSTRAINT `vAuthorID`
   FOREIGN KEY (`vAuthorID`)
   REFERENCES `proquotes`.`author_info` (`vAuthorID`)
```

The last parenthesis for the `REFERENCES` clause should reference an attribute in `author_info`, and not from `thquotes`. Therefore you may need to change `vAuthorID` accordingly.

Comment: i did that. now it says: `ERROR 1005: Can't create table 'proquotes.thquotes' (errno: 150)`

Comment: @fusion: What MySQL version are you using? You may need to create an index manually on `author_info.vAuthorID`. Source: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,19755,19755#msg-19755

Comment: @fusion: ... Or else, it might that `author_info.vAuthorID` is not the exact same data type as `thquotes.vAuthorID`.  Source: http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/mysql/mysql-error-1005-hy000

Comment: i've updated the question with the sql query of author_info. please take a look at it.

Comment: @fusion: OK, it looks like  `vAuthorID` in the new table `thquotes` is a `VARCHAR(8)`, but in the `author_info` table it is an `INT`. They have to be the same data type. One of them needs to change. If you want to change the `thquotes` table, try replacing `vAuthorID VARCHAR(8) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL ,` with `vAuthorID INT NOT NULL ,`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a column name in the parentheses after the `INDEX` keyword?

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html.

Answer (score 0):

The three obvious errors are a lack of fields in your INDEX and FOREIGN KEY definitions. You have to specify one or more fields for each, otherwise it's a syntax error.

```
INDEX `vAuthorID` () ,  <--need a field here in the ()'s
CONSTRAINT `vAuthorID`
    FOREIGN KEY ()  <---another field here in the ()'s
    REFERENCES `proquotes`.`author_info` ()  <--and yet another field here in the ()'s
```

You're also not specifying which database engine to use, which generally means MySQL will use MyISAM, so all of your foreign key specifications will be silently dropped.